# Android - Sometimes can not get json from https link

Tags: android

I am having a problem about `ssl` . I connect to the `https` link and get `json` from it . It works well but sometimes it can not connect and get `json` from it. The result is that my app is crashed. I think it must have a method to open the connection and get json from https .

I tested it in LG Optimus G with `Android 4.1.2`.

This is my error logs :

```
10-24 04:10:59.149: W/System.err(9985): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
10-24 04:10:59.149: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
10-24 04:10:59.169: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:395)
10-24 04:10:59.169: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:647)
10-24 04:10:59.189: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:618)
10-24 04:10:59.209: I/MiuiMagnifierController(9985): MagnifierController is created
10-24 04:10:59.219: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.<init>(SocketInputBuffer.java:70)
10-24 04:10:59.229: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:83)
10-24 04:10:59.229: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:170)
10-24 04:10:59.229: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:106)
10-24 04:10:59.229: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:129)
10-24 04:10:59.229: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:172)
10-24 04:10:59.239: W/System.err(9985):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
```

This is my function I used :

```
public static String readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {

    String result = "";
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;

    httpClient = httpClient();
    httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpResponse httpResponseGet = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    HttpEntity resEntityGet = httpResponseGet.getEntity();

    result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);

    if (result.contains("\n")) {
        result = result.replace("\n", "");
    }
    return result;
}
```

=> It is be crashed in line : `HttpResponse httpResponseGet = httpClient.execute(httpPost);`

Can you give me some solutions that can pass this problems ?

Comment: does your URL use https or http?

Comment: It says "connection closed by peer". Did you look into the log files on the server side?

Comment: I used the https link . http link worked normally . There aren't any errors in the log in server.